# Can I run Cloudify or other open source PaaS on my existing servers?

Tags: cloud, openshift, paas, cloudify

I'm new in Cloud Computing world, sorry if my question is basic. I know most of the PaaS are built to run on top of IaaS, but 
I want to know if it is possible to run Cloudify or other PaaS (like OpenShift, Flynn, etc.) on non-virtualized servers? 
I'd like to take advantages of using PaaS but without having any IaaS, is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding Cloudify, you certainly can run on bare metal, including Windows.  You also can orchestrate physical hardware (e.g. routers, switches).  Workloads can be containerized or not.  Or both.  You can simply hardcode IP addresses for something quick and dirty, or use our host pool plugin, that simulates an IAAS layer by managing a pool of IPs.  You can orchestrate by pure command line or run a manager which provides a dashboard with metrics.

You'll first need to grab the [CLI] http://docs.getcloudify.org/3.4.1/installation/from-packages/.  Then if you want to run the manager, bootstrap the [simple manager](https://github.com/cloudify-cosmo/cloudify-manager-blueprints).  With or without the manager, you'll be ready to try creating a blueprint.  The [host pool plugin](https://github.com/cloudify-cosmo/cloudify-host-pool-plugin) will help.  See the README for the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

With OpenShit V3, based around Kubernetes and the container runtime engine containerd, you can definitely do that.

- https://docs.openshift.org/latest/welcome/index.html

Installation is via an Ansible playbook. In brief, you set up ssh access to your nodes from a machine you are going to run the install from, ensure certain ports are accessible between machines, set up the configuration describing the machines you have etc and run Ansible.

You can find a video which shows the process at:

- https://blog.openshift.com/openshift-developers-set-full-cluster-30-minutes/

to get an idea of what is involved.